# How do I actually add DRM to a video file for EME to interpret?

Tags: html5-video, drm, eme

So, I’ve tried googling this a bit but DRM and EME search results haven’t pulled up much in the way of actually telling me what to use on the server-side to implement DRM before a video is sent to the browser for the HTML5 player to decode. Is there some sort of ubuntu/Apache plug-in that adds drm to a video file on the fly then streams the DRM’d file to the HTML 5 video tag?

Comment: search google for CENC

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shaka Packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager) to package content, so it would be DRMed.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I have some video content I'm starting to release and would prefer for it to be more difficult to be saved to a user's device than just using a normal HTML5 video tag alone - which allows anyone to download the full video file. I'm sure no scheme is 100% but I don't think there are many known work-arounds to this.